django_get_or_create doesn't let me create instances
I'm using ModelFactory through SubFactory and there was django_get_or_create Meta field with ('code') inside. I put my 2 new added to model fields to this field django_get_or_create and it literally stopped making countries with 'RU' code and didint fill my array? There's an issue with this field or im doing something really wrong?
I did try to search for similar problem but didn't find anything
[
class ModelFactory(DjangoModelFactory):
    code = "RU"
    predefined_amounts_one_time = [500, 1000, 3000]
    predefined_amounts_recurring = [500, 1000, 3000]

    class Meta:
        model = Model
        django_get_or_create = ("predefined_amounts_one_time", "predefined_amounts_recurring", "code")]

1
this is what i get multiple times in tests when i try to print those fields:
Turkey
[]
Turkey is an aliase to TR
